# Are all Galois extensions simple?

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory, galois-extensions

I have been looking at Galois extensions and Galois groups and have been wondering if all Galois extensions are simple. I don't think this is true.

For example with $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{3}) = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2} + \sqrt{3})$ would be a simple extension of $\mathbb{Q}$.

With something like $\mathbb{Q}(i,\sqrt{3})$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ this is Galois, but I don't think it is simple. Is that correct? My initial guess was that $\mathbb{Q}(i,\sqrt{3}) = \mathbb{Q}(i\sqrt{3})$, but I think the right side is just a subfield.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_element_theorem

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is a well-known result that:

> Every finite separable extension is simple.

See the [Primitive element theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_element_theorem).

Thus, yes, all finite Galois extensions are simple.

Infinite Galois extension cannot be simple as every simple *algebraic* extension is of course finite; basically this is  the definition of an element being algebraic.

Let me add that for the specific example, as mentioned in comments, one can take for example $ i + \sqrt{3}$. You are correct that $i \sqrt{3}$ will not work; as it is a root of $X^2+3$ and thus its degree is only two.

It is the third subfield of degree $2$; the other two are the ones generated by $i$ and $\sqrt{3}$ respectively.

Under a Galois theory angle one can say that those elements $\alpha$ work as generators that are not fixed by any of the three non-identity elements of the Galois group, and thus have four conjugates.

Differently the only ones that do not work are those fixed by some non-identity element of the Galois group. These are $i$ and its rational multiples, $\sqrt{3}$ and its rational multiples, and $i\sqrt{3}$ and its rational multiples.

Comment: What if the extension is not finite though?

Comment: An infinite algebraic extension is never simple. I suspect that OP only has finite extensions in mind.  But yes it would be better to be explicit.

Comment: Oh yes, of course. I forgot for a moment that an infinite simple extension is transcendental, hence not Galois.

Comment: Just a follow-up: In my example then, what is $\alpha$ such that $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha) = \mathbb{Q}(i,\sqrt{3})$?

Comment: @JohnDoe $i + \sqrt{3}$ will work, since $(i + \sqrt{3})^2 = 2 + 2i\sqrt{3}$, so you have $i\sqrt{3}$, but then $(i\sqrt{3})(i + \sqrt{3}) = -\sqrt{3} + 3i$, which you can add to $i + \sqrt{3}$ so you have $4i$, so you have $i$.

Comment: @JohnDoe, the proof of the primitive element theorem shows that (in some sense) almost any choice works. In the field $\mathbf{Q}(\sqrt{r},\sqrt{s})$, the element $a + b \sqrt{r} + c \sqrt{s} + d \sqrt{rs}$ is primitive as long as at least $2$ of $b$, $c$, and $d$ is non-zero.

Comment: @JohnDoe while it's already answered in comments I expanded the answer a bit.